# Generating client certificates for IIS webapp

Tags: iis, windows-7, ssl, iis-7.5, ssl-certificate

I am trying to figure out how to set up my web application so that only clients (external) with issued certificates could access it. (on Windows7)

I have followd this [tutorial](http://ondrej.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/iis-7-and-client-certificates/) where i got a .CER and .PVK that i could use for creating client certificates with **makecert.exe**

But the problem was that I could not import a .CER file to server.
When i followed this [tutorial](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-microsoft-iis-7.htm) i got an error

> Cannot find the certificate request associated with this certificate
>   file. A certificate request must be completed on the computer where it
>   was created.

I was told that i have to create the .CER via CER Authority, so I got myself a Windows Server and installed Active Directory Certificate services where i first created the request in IIS and issued myself a .CER file that I could normally import in my IIS on Windows7.

But now when I try to create client certificates I am missing private key file.

Can some one please help me with this issue, since I have never fone this before and I am having trouble understanding the procedure.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're looking at doing certificate-based authentication against your website/web-app?  Or you want to install an SSL-cert so your website/app can accept `https` connections?  They're two different things, and if it's the first one (like it sounds like), that would be your problem - you're following tutorials for the other thing.  Let me know, and update your question (information about if you have, or are willing/able to create a Certificate Authority in your domain would be helpful too), and I can get back to you. I've had to deal with this certificate thing a bunch lately.

Comment: Exactly! I want to issue a server certificate and then whole bunch of client certificates, so that only clients with issued certificates in their browser could access the application. The application is hosted on Windows7 with only one account available. But i have Windows server 2008 available with Certificate Authority installed.